# User alternating between ClaimsPrincipal and WindowsPrincipal

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have inherited an internal website (NET6/MVC) that is set to allow both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication.  Mostly, it works.  The controllers with attributes like `[Authorize(Policy = Policy.SupportRead)]` seem to do their job.  However...

I have sections where the user name is required from AD.  In the controller if I use `HttpContext.User` I seem to get ambiguous results after a user is logged in.  Sometimes I get a ClaimsPrincipal, that is essentially empty, and sometimes I get the proper WindowsPrincipal.  I can just refresh the page and it will get different results.

I'm honestly not sure where to start with this, here's some of the relevant code.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
         options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
     });

     services.AddAuthentication(o =>
     {
         o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         o.DefaultChallengeScheme = HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     }).AddIdentityCookies();

     PolicyConfig.ConfigurePolicies(services);
 }
```

Later on in startup

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllers();
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Login controller method is very simple, honestly surprised this works, not sure what magic is happening.  When the link to this method is clicked I get a chrome popup asking for windows credentials.

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

But then I go here and user swaps between the two, WindowsPrincipal and ClaimsPrincipal, randomly each request.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Dashboard()
{
    var user = User;
    ....
}
```

Not a lot of experience with web auth.  I don't think I have any related 3rd party nuget packages.  Looks like just Microsoft.AspNetCode.Identity.

Pretty sure everything I've tried so far is just blind shots in the dark.  Tried to call `Logout()` in the login method since it seems like I'm logged in twice.  Tried messing with the startup config.  Tried removing that `ResponseCache` attribute since I don't *really* know what it's doing.  Looked in Chrome Dev tools for a security cookie, which I'm not seeing as far as I can tell.

The closest thing I've found that relates to this is
[User.Identity fluctuates between ClaimsIdentity and WindowsIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236994/user-identity-fluctuates-between-claimsidentity-and-windowsidentity)
But I'm not quite sure it's the same.  User.Identities.Count is always 1 in my case.

If I keep repeatedly logging in on the site eventually it seems to stick, but obviously not a great user experience.

Let me know if I need to provide more code.

EDIT:  From the linked issue, `var user = HttpContext.Features.Get<WindowsPrincipal>();` this always returns null for me.

Comment: `User.Identities.Count is always 1 in my case`  You can try to specify ***AuthenticationSchemes*** with the `Authorize` attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme},{HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]` , then you can access the [multiple identities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PAm5.png).

Comment: InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Cookies'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, Windows.

Didn't work but at least I get more information about what may be going on.

Comment: Have you tried `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{"Identity.Application"},{HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]`?

Comment: Tried `Identity.Application` and `Windows`.  They run just fine and seem to log me in as usual, but don't fix the problem :(  
I've also tried putting `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in the `web.config`.  It seemed like it helped at first but now it's doing the same thing.